# creating a textfile in a different directory

Tags: php

i created a text a file in the current directory using getcwd(), now i need create the text in a different directory. but i cant figure out how to go back using only php

what it did before

when im at

```
/var/www/website/mydomain/
```

the code is

```
$objData = serialize($name). "\r\n";
            $createPath = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."mytextdir/".$id.".txt";
            echo $createPath;
            $fp = fopen($createPath, "w");
            fwrite($fp, unserialize($objData));
            fclose($fp);
```

it creates the text in

```
/var/www/website/mydomain/mytextdir/###.txt
```

but now i need to create this text file on

```
/var/www/website/allTextfiles/###.txt
```

is this possible if so, can anybody help me on how to do it using something similer to this technique

```
getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."#####/".$##.".txt";
```

Answer (score 2):

With double-dot you get to a higher folder.

So your path changes into this:

```
getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "allTextFiles/".$id.".txt";
```

Comment: thanks but it does not detect the ".." it just takes it as a string

Comment: @SoththiUpali true that, but when using it as a path, it will work